# Can I connect to datalab via ssh

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-shell

The scenario is I have set up a Datalab instance in my cloud Project A. I would like to be able to connect to this instance and use Datalab from cloud shell in Project B.

At the moment I have a Datalab instance created in Project A called "test-instance-datalab" this instance runs my Datalab notebook:

**Instance name in Project A:**

[image]

**Datalab Notebook for Project A:**

[image]

I can connect to this instance using SSH via the cloud shell inside Project B:

[image]

However I cannot connect to Datalab even though I managed to connect to the correct instance.

Is it possible to use Datalab in a instance via SSH from the google cloud shell in a different project?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are treating the Cloud Shell instance in Project B as if it were a desktop, so you should be able to connect the same way as from a desktop.

Cloud Shell should include the [datalab command line tool](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/tree/master/tools/cli).  You should be able to specify Project A and the instance to connect to, and then open up the Cloud Shell Web Preview window to see Datalab, but otherwise following the normal Datalab instuctions: https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts

Edit: correction, Cloud Shell should already have the datalab tool.